# adding multiple images in drawable

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am making a city guide app which includes multiple images of the city. After adding multiple images in drawable and getting these images, my app is not working properly.What is the best way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. `my app is not working properly` is a poor question as it gives no detail as to what you are doing or what errors you are encountering. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54777766/edit) your question with updates.

Comment: how it not working properly ?

Comment: what problem you are facing in your application

Comment: please share some more detail like code explains what are you doing exactly in code.